# Python Tesseract cyrillic characters problem

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to create a script that will highlight specific words inside images using tesseract. 
My approach works fine for most languages except languages with Cyrillic characters like Russian or Greek.

[For example usinng this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWNhK.png), when I extract the text using tesseract image_to_string it is printed correctly (see below)

[Extracted using image_to_string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmFmy.png)

But when I try to process the image and highlight the desired text using tesseract data["text"], I get a text that does not contain Cyrillic characters (see below)

[Example 1 data["text"]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SG8S6.png)

[Example 2 data["text"]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFwBQ.png)

I understood that tesseract already encode the characters and I tried to encode one more time but I get the same results. Maybe my approach is wrong ?

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import urllib

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image = cv2.imread("test_russian.png")

target_word = ["длинной"]

# Process image: morph and invert
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 1))
processed = cv2.morphologyEx(gray_image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
inverted = 255 - processed

# Extract text
words_string = pytesseract.image_to_string(inverted, lang='rus', config='--psm 6')
print(f"Text extracted using image_to_string: \n {words_string}")

# Copy image to get data
image_copy = image.copy()
data = pytesseract.image_to_data(inverted, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)

# Search for word
for word in target_word:
    print(f"\n from target word {word} and lowered {word.lower()} \n")
word_occurences = [i for i, word in enumerate(data["text"]) if word.lower() == word.lower() in target_word]

print("Text from data['text']: ")
for i, word in enumerate(data["text"]):
    print(f"I : {i} and word: {word}")

for occ in word_occurences:
    print(f"Occ: {occ}")
    w = data["width"][occ]
    h = data["height"][occ]
    l = data["left"][occ]
    t = data["top"][occ]
    p1 = (l + w, t + h)
    p2 = (l, t + h)

    image_copy = cv2.line(image_copy, p1, p2, color=(0, 60, 255), thickness=2)

# Resize images
image_copy = cv2.resize(image_copy, (920, 640))
gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (920, 640))
inverted_image = cv2.resize(inverted, (920, 640))

# Show and save image
cv2.imshow("proccesed and inverted", inverted_image)
cv2.imshow("gray", gray_image)
cv2.imshow("identified text", image_copy)

cv2.imwrite("identified_text.png", image_copy)

cv2.waitKey(0)
``
```

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably encoding.
Have you tried to output the text to a file. You can save files with different encodings.
You can output the text to a .txt file and then choose to save it under "UTF8" encoding. This usually displays cyrillic characters.
If this doesn't help, there are online converters with a wider range of encodings. See if they are any good.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has happened to me as when using non Latin alphabet based text. I  do not know how it was resolved but I changed my code as:

1. OCR file first using a different language than the file actually have.For example; convert greek text containing file as if it contains russian text.
2. Repeat same process for the original language.

Namely, trying to convert the file other than thier original content and then change to its original language solved the issue for me. My codes are below:

```
def FileExtrationOCR(Rawpdffile="Rawpdf.pdf",
                     Rawimagefile="Rawimage.jpg",
                     pagenotoextract=0,
                     OCRfile="Searchable.pdf",
                     lang=None):
    ...

    # Searchable PDF creation section
    pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(Rawimagefile, extension='pdf', lang=lang)
    pdf_dict = pytesseract.image_to_data(Rawimagefile, output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT, lang=lang)
    pdf_bytes = pytesseract.image_to_data(Rawimagefile, output_type=pytesseract.Output.BYTES, lang=lang)
    
    ....
   
a = FileExtrationOCR(Rawpdffile="Arm.pdf", pagenotoextract=0, lang="rus")
```

Firstly, I did not pass the "lang" paramater in "a"
Then pass the parameter as above.